# MoviePy in Django: Failed to read the duration of the file

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, moviepy

I'm trying to pass the video data pulled from a ModelsForm into a moviepy method, however the VideoFileClip() function is unable to read the duration of the file.

I've checked the data I'm pulling in and it is the correct name. Currently the issue may be that I'm passing it in as a string. However, without this it returns an error : 'Splitter' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Please see the error and my code below. Thanks for your help!

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CNfq.png)
[Models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGwJJ.png)

**Error Message**

```
OSError at /highlights/
MoviePy error: failed to read the duration of file <highlights.splitter.Splitter object at 0x000001A82CE553D0>.
Here are the file infos returned by ffmpeg:

ffmpeg version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20181017
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
<highlights.splitter.Splitter object at 0x000001A82CE553D0>: Invalid argument
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/highlights/
Django Version: 3.0.1
Exception Type: OSError
Exception Value:    
MoviePy error: failed to read the duration of file <highlights.splitter.Splitter object at 0x000001A82CE553D0>.
Here are the file infos returned by ffmpeg:

ffmpeg version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20181017
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
<highlights.splitter.Splitter object at 0x000001A82CE553D0>: Invalid argument
Exception Location: C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py in ffmpeg_parse_infos, line 289
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Codes\\highlightreel',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python38',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions']
Server time:    Wed, 1 Apr 2020 20:04:23 +0000
```

**Traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/highlights/

Django Version: 3.0.1
Python Version: 3.8.0
Installed Applications:
['highlights.apps.HighlightsConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 285, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    line = [l for l in lines if keyword in l][index]

During handling of the above exception (list index out of range), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Codes\highlightreel\highlights\views.py", line 17, in video_form_upload
    Splitter(val)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Codes\highlightreel\highlights\splitter.py", line 18, in __init__
    clip = mp.VideoFileClip(str(file))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.reader = FFMPEG_VideoReader(filename, pix_fmt=pix_fmt,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 35, in __init__
    infos = ffmpeg_parse_infos(filename, print_infos, check_duration,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 289, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    raise IOError(("MoviePy error: failed to read the duration of file %s.\n"

Exception Type: OSError at /highlights/
Exception Value: MoviePy error: failed to read the duration of file <highlights.splitter.Splitter object at 0x000001A82CE553D0>.
Here are the file infos returned by ffmpeg:

ffmpeg version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20181017
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
<highlights.splitter.Splitter object at 0x000001A82CE553D0>: Invalid argument
```

**UPDATE**

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqGII.png)

**Error**

```
AttributeError at /highlights/
'Splitter' object has no attribute 'endswith'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/highlights/
Django Version: 3.0.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Splitter' object has no attribute 'endswith'
Exception Location: C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py in ffmpeg_parse_infos, line 244
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Codes\\highlightreel',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python38',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions']
Server time:    Thu, 2 Apr 2020 00:57:52 +0000
```

**Traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/highlights/

Django Version: 3.0.1
Python Version: 3.8.0
Installed Applications:
['highlights.apps.HighlightsConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Codes\highlightreel\highlights\views.py", line 16, in video_form_upload
    splitter = Splitter(instance.video.path)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Codes\highlightreel\highlights\splitter.py", line 20, in __init__
    clip = mp.VideoFileClip(file)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.reader = FFMPEG_VideoReader(filename, pix_fmt=pix_fmt,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 35, in __init__
    infos = ffmpeg_parse_infos(filename, print_infos, check_duration,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 244, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    is_GIF = filename.endswith('.gif')

Exception Type: AttributeError at /highlights/
Exception Value: 'Splitter' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Comment: I checked the source code of the packages you are using, and passing the filename seems to be the right way of calling `VideoFileClip`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be passing just the filename of the uploaded video, when you should be passing the whole path to the file.

Try any of the following, but whatever it is, the issue seems to be the libraries not being able to load the correct file. Make sure first the videos are being uploaded in your media folder. If you can verify this, then you know it's now only a matter of loading it.

### Option 1 - Change the view

In your `video_form_upload` view, try the following

```
def video_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VideoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
             instance = form.save()  # get the saved model
             splitter = Splitter(instance.video.path)  # get the video file from the saved model
             return redirect(`highlights`)
    ...
```

### Option 2 - Change the splitter

In your `Splitter` class, line 18, try changing it from

```
clip = mp.VideoFileClip(str(file))
```

to

```
clip = mp.VideoFileClip(file.path)
```

Comment: That would make sense!

Although it doesn't look like the path exists:

AttributeError at /highlights/
'Splitter' object has no attribute 'path'

Is there a better way to be operating on the uploaded video?

Comment: Tried option one and it's passing through correctly but back to the duration error.

I've checked that the video is uploading to the correct location fine, it appears to be struggling to load it in :/ 

Any other ideas by any chance?

Comment: Were you able to confirm you are passing the file's absolute path?

Comment: actually I outputted what it's passing and it's sending through:

<highlights.splitter.Splitter object at 0x000002313C68A490>

rather than the path

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of your current code with the print/log statements and the output